# Single page web app connectionString error

Tags: abp

i have successfully deployed multilayered app to heroku.
Now i am trying to do the same with single layer web app and its acting weird.

It is working on my local machine with no issues. But when i deploy it on heroku (i did the db migration and logged into heroku db to make sure.)

And now when i run app i get
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString'). I cant figure out why its throwing that error, i didnt changed anything.

```
2022-06-01T16:46:05.058614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=kriptodonacija.herokuapp.com request_id=30d7bf9f-eda8-43c1-baaf-10ce5792aa44 fwd="94.189.137.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=130 protocol=https
2022-06-01T16:46:05.057150+00:00 app[web.1]: [16:46:05 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://kriptodonacija.herokuapp.com/ - -
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060435+00:00 app[web.1]: [16:46:05 ERR] Connection id "0HMI3T8NBRKQO", Request id "0HMI3T8NBRKQO:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060447+00:00 app[web.1]: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.SettingManagementDbContext -> λ:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.SettingManagementDbContext, Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060448+00:00 app[web.1]: ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060449+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060450+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.UseNpgsql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 npgsqlOptionsAction)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060451+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContextConfigurationContextPostgreSqlExtensions.UseNpgsql(AbpDbContextConfigurationContext context, Action`1 postgreSqlOptionsAction)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060451+00:00 app[web.1]: at CryptoDonor.CryptoDonorModule.<>c.<ConfigureEfCore>b__14_2(AbpDbContextConfigurationContext configurationContext) in /tmp/build_1a1be254/CryptoDonor/CryptoDonorModule.cs:line 290
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060452+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.DependencyInjection.DbContextOptionsFactory.Configure[TDbContext](AbpDbContextOptions options, AbpDbContextConfigurationContext`1 context)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060452+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.DependencyInjection.DbContextOptionsFactory.Create[TDbContext](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060453+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacRegistration.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Register>b__0(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060454+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060454+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__2_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060457+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060457+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060458+00:00 app[web.1]: --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060459+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060459+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060460+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060461+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060461+00:00 app[web.1]: at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060462+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060462+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Uow.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.CreateDbContextAsync(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060462+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Uow.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.CreateDbContextAsync(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, String connectionStringName, String connectionString)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060463+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Uow.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWorkDbContextProvider`1.GetDbContextAsync()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060463+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreRepository`2.GetDbSetAsync()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060465+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreSettingRepository.GetListAsync(String providerName, String providerKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060466+00:00 app[web.1]: at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060466+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060467+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.SettingManagementStore.SetCacheItemsAsync(String providerName, String providerKey, String currentName, SettingCacheItem currentCacheItem)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060470+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.SettingManagementStore.GetCacheItemAsync(String name, String providerName, String providerKey)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060470+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.SettingManagementStore.GetOrNullAsync(String name, String providerName, String providerKey)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060471+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060474+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060475+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Settings.TenantSettingValueProvider.GetOrNullAsync(SettingDefinition setting)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060476+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Settings.SettingProvider.GetOrNullValueFromProvidersAsync(IEnumerable`1 providers, SettingDefinition setting)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060477+00:00 app[web.1]: at Volo.Abp.Settings.SettingProvider.GetOrNullAsync(String name)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060480+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.DefaultAbpRequestLocalizationOptionsProvider.GetLocalizationOptionsAsync()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060480+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060482+00:00 app[web.1]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
2022-06-01T16:46:05.060483+00:00 app[web.1]: --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When i was creating git, .gitignore file had appsettings in it. So i didnt push config to heroku. after including it all works well.